# Quicktags: Cannot make a span class

Tags: quicktag

Edit: The solution is as follows:
Needed to use `<span class=\"title\">` instead of `<span class="title">`.

---

I am trying to adding custom quicktags like this:

```
function wporg_add_quicktag_paragraph() {
    wp_add_inline_script(
        'quicktags',
        "QTags.addButton( 'title_tag', 'title', '<span class="title">', '</span>', '', '', 1);"
    );
}
add_action( 'admin_enqueue_scripts', 'wporg_add_quicktag_paragraph' );
```

Using `<span class="title">` throws an error. But if I change `<span class="title">` to `<span>`, it works fine.

I was able to add `<span class="title">` as a quicktag until the Wordpress 6.0 update. My new code is based of this: https://developer.wordpress.org/apis/quicktags/

Thanks in advance

Comment: *I'm guessing you got a PHP error, right?* Because **`'<span class="title">'` did work for me**, except that I used `\"` instead of just `"`. So be careful with your quotes, i.e. *escape* them as necessary, and if you haven't, [enable debugging](https://wordpress.org/documentation/article/debugging-in-wordpress/) so that you can ensure your code is free from errors/warnings.

Comment: Thank you, Sally. I didn't know '<span class=\"title\">' was thing. That solves it.